# Navigation Rest api

Tags: rest, navigation, performance, global-navigation

I have a structural navigation on a site collection on sharepoint online, I want to create a custom navigation control using rest api that show 2 level, so I made a query :

```
_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/navigation/menustate?mapprovidername='GlobalNavigationSwitchableProvider'"
```

this query is working as expected the problem is that it took at least 14s to return the result.

did anyone have any other idea that is faster than this ?

Comment: We have on-prem 2013 and the call takes about 450 milliseconds. Don't know if that helps, but it seems it shouldn't take as long as it is for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using 0365 / SP Online then this is a known issue. Structural navigation can result in major performance issues. This is why even Microsoft [recommends to use mananged navigation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/navigation-options-for-sharepoint-online#using-structural-navigation-in-sharepoint-online) instead of structural.